# c++ - cout of same variable but different output when accessed within or out of class

Tags: c++

I'm building a simple `Shader` class. `Shader` class has a `const char* _src` member variable and is loaded in the constructor.

However, the outputs of

```
std::cout << _src << std::endl; // access within class
```

and

```
std::cout << fs._src << std::endl; // access out of class,fs is a Shader instance
```

are totally different. While the first gives correct result, the latter one output some meaningless character:

output 1

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 color;

void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
        color = aColor;
}
```

output 2

```
αG╬▀
```

`Shader.h`

```
class Shader {
public:
    const char *_src;
    GLuint _type;

    Shader(const char *fn, GLuint type);

private:
    bool loadSource(const char *fn);
};
```

`Shader.cpp`

```
#include "Shader.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

Shader::Shader(const char *fn, GLuint type)
: _type(type) {
    loadSource(fn);
}

bool Shader::loadSource(const char *fn) {
    std::ifstream file(fn);
    if (!file.good())
        return false;

    std::string line, src;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        src += line + '\n';
    }
    _src = src.c_str();

    std::cout << _src << std::endl;

    file.close();
    return true;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
int main() {
    Shader fs("vertex_shader.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    std::cout << fs._src << std::endl;
}
```

The two `cout` appear in `main()` and `Shader::loadSource()`.

`vertex_shader.glsl`

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

out vec3 color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    color = aColor;
}
```

What is wrong??

Comment: Use a `std::string` instead of a `char*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic example of "leaking" the address of the local:
`_src = src.c_str();`. `src` is destroyed along with everything pointed at by `_src` once the `loadSource` call ends.

You need to either make a proper copy to `_src`, or use std::string directly instead to avoid such bugs.

Comment: Should probably also mention that this is everyone's favourite phrase, "Undefined Behaviour" - and that it could do pretty much anything it wants to; the printing of a random character is just what it does in this case for this compiler for the given compiler flags...